# What's the best way to assign a case role via the API?

Tags: api, civicase

When you assign a case role through the UI it creates lines in the relationships and activities tables. I can't find an equivalent through the API - I can create the relationship (which then shows correctly in the case UI), but it doesn't create any activity lines. Does that matter? Or is there a better way?

Edit: Running on Civi 4.5.8 on WordPress.

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you working with?

Comment: 4.5.8 - have updated the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the api code for relationships it doesn't appear to be case-aware. You can duplicate what happens in the UI by checking out CRM_Contact_Page_Ajax::relationship(), and note near the bottom where it calls CRM_Case_BAO_Case::createCaseRoleActivity().

Depending on what you mean by "api", that might not be exactly what you're looking for, but you should just be able to add a call to CRM_Case_BAO_Case::createCaseRoleActivity() to the code you've written that already creates the relationship.

Comment: brill - thank you for digging into the code on that one.